# Can you skip some dependencies when installing an npm package from a git repository?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm currently working with 2 private react projects, both using a single private component library which gets installed from git ("library": "git+ssh://git...#commitref").

The component library has a lot of additional devDependencies, most of which are not related to building the library at all. The component library's devDependencies in package.json includes stuff like typescript, jest, testing-library and storybook, however to successfully build this package only typescript and type declarations are needed. (It is built simply by running tsc -d.) Regardless of this fact, everything else included in devDependencies gets installed, which can slow things down quite a bit.

Is there some way, when installing an npm package from a git repository, to skip installing some of it's dependencies? Such as being able to have npm recognize the difference between build-time requirements and other devDependencies? I have already tried moving heavier stuff - like storybook - into optionalDependencies, but those got installed anyway.

EDIT: Im thinking about moving non-buildtime devDependencies into peerDependencies, marking them as optional and running 'npx npm-install-peers' when developing on the component library, I do hope there is a better aproach to this issue.

Comment: `npm install` does not install dependencies' `devDependencies`; rather, it only installs dependencies' `dependencies`  For example, in a clean directory: `npm init` then `npm install bootstrap`.  Look in `node_modules` and note that none of bootstrap's `devDependencies` are installed.

Comment: @benbotto It does install devDependencies, as long as there is a 'prepare' script in the package.json (which in this case - there is, it just only runs tsc). See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install on installing from git remote url.

Comment: Gotcha.  A `prepare` script wasn't mentioned in the question.
Is the `prepare` script necessary?  That is, would it be possible to build the component library and publish the build, for example in a release in the GitHub repo, or better yet in a private npm package?  Generally TS libraries are built and then the dist is published.

Comment: @benbotto Obviously, a private npm package would be the best and easiest option, but I'm looking into other options as well, as the library would be the only package hosted in a private registry. A solution I'm thinking about replacing the prepare command with the postinstall command - and moving typescript into dependencies from devDependencies. In theory this should prevent other devDependencies from getting installed, but I will have to try it out. Another option I have left is packaging the library into a tarball in CI and downloading it as an artifact - but I'd rather not take this route

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm install --production`, but it will ignore all `devDependencies`

Comment: That is not what I mean, I want to skip installing my dependency's devDepencencies.

Comment: Got it. I have only one idea, is using `postinstall` script. But it won't be obviously

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me npm install --force

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).